# Verifying the Triangle Inequality for a function d

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, proof-writing

Let $\mathcal X$ denote the set of all sequences of real numbers. I need to show that for $x,y\in\mathcal X$ 
$$
d(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{|x_n-y_n|}{2^n(1+|x_n-y_n|)}
$$
satisfies the Triangle Inequality. I've gotten to the point where it is clear that 
$$
d(x,z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{|x_n-z_n|}{2^n(1+|x_n-z_n|)}\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{|x_n-y_n|+|y_n-z_n|}{2^n(1+|x_n-y_n|+|y_n-z_n|)}
$$

but I'm not sure how to get to $d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$. That is I'm not sure how to separate the denominator to get the desired fraction in order to get $d(x,y)+d(y,z)$.

Can anyone explain how to get through this last step to show that this metric satisfies the Triangle Inequality? We've studied some useful inequalities like H$\ddot{\text o}$lder's and Minkowski's Inequality, but I'm not sure if they can or should be applied here.

Are one or more of these inequalities required to show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{|x_n-y_n|+|y_n-z_n|}{2^n(1+|x_n-y_n|+|y_n-z_n|)}\overset{?}\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{|x_n-y_n|}{2^n(1+|x_n-y_n|)}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{|y_n-z_n|}{2^n(1+|y_n-z_n|)}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{|x_n-y_n|+|y_n-z_n|}{1+|x_n-y_n|+|y_n-z_n|}=\frac{|x_n-y_n|}{1+|x_n-y_n|+|y_n-z_n|}+\frac{|y_n-z_n|}{1+|x_n-y_n|+|y_n-z_n|}\le\frac{|x_n-y_n|}{1+|x_n-y_n|}+\frac{|y_n-z_n|}{1+|y_n-z_n|}$$

Comment: What about the $2^n$ factor? Is that not a concern?

Comment: of course not, you can add any positive constant both sides.

Comment: So it is completely because the denominator on the left of the inequality is bigger than the denominator on the right of the inequality?

Comment: yeah, you are right.